# How do I write a spec for particular function in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

I need to write spec for following function in Jasmine.

```
export function getComponent<T>(ele: HTMLElement, comp: string): T {
    let instance: T;
    for (let i = 0; i < (<DomElements>(ele as HTMLElement)).ej2_instances.length; i++) {
        instance = <T>(ele as DomElements).ej2_instances[i];
        let compName: string = (instance as { getModuleName: () => string } & T).getModuleName();
        if (comp === compName) {
            return instance;
        }
    } 
    return undefined;
}
```

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
describe('getcomponent function', (): void => {
    let instance: string;
    let componentname: string;
    function test(instance, componentname) {
        it('if statement', function () {
            expect(instance).toEqual(componentname)
        });
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < instance.length; i++) {
        test(instance[i], componentname[i])
    }
})
```

Comment: When you say "it didn't work", what specifically didn't work? Did the test fail? Did the test not run? Help us to help you

Comment: yes bro, the test case was not cover my function

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this code, it will help you to get your solution**

```js
describe("getcomponent funtion", function () {
    it("if statement", function () {
        let comp: any= {ej2_instances:[new Touch()]};
        expect(getComponent(comp, 'touch') instanceof Touch).toBe(true);
    });
    it("else statement", function () {
        let comps: any= {ej2_instances:[new Touch()]};
        expect(getComponent(comps, 'button') instanceof Touch).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro, it worked but i met some errors i can clear those. thank you. i will accept this as my answer